# Can anyone explain below block of code from shipping.js in magento2

Tags: magento2, shipping, shipping-methods

```
            selectShippingMethod: function (shippingMethod) {
        **selectShippingMethodAction(shippingMethod);**
        checkoutData.setSelectedShippingRate(shippingMethod['carrier_code'] + '_' + shippingMethod['method_code']);

        return true;
    },
```

> selectShippingMethodAction(shippingMethod);

where is this method?

Comment: you can see this methods in 

`/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/cart/shipping-rates.js` 

**and** 

`/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/checkout-data-resolver.js`

Comment: No i want to know that how selectShippingMethodAction worked as function instead  of object